# php paypal integration IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to understand for a couple of days how is working the PayPal payment through IPN and all this things but I think my PHP level is not that high.

I am just trying to make a script like this.

Registered user on my website wants to download some content wich is allowed only for VIP User group and I need to add the BUY VIP function so… I set up sandbox, created Buy now button added to my website, created success and cancel page, created `http://mysite/ipn.php` page to recieve notifications the thing is that I'm not sure what should I write in ipn.php for execute next function after purchase:

```
UPDATE users set user_group='VIP' where id='$buyerid'
```

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php

Comment: tried this one setted up payment working but nothing changing in DB... still not working... can't understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you share the code please